# Star number equals product of consecutive star numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, recreational-mathematics, analytic-number-theory, quartics

A [star number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_number) is a number of the form $6n(n-1)+1$. They are equal to the number of dots in a star, like this:

[image]

According to Wikipedia:

> Unique among the star numbers is 35113, since its prime factors (i.e., 13, 37 and 73) are also consecutive star numbers.

This statement does not give a source. It is not clear in what way 35113 is 'unique'. After some experimenting, I arrived at the following conjecture:

> The only star number that can be written as the product of at least 2 consecutive star numbers larger than 1, is 35113.

For products of $2,3,4$ successive star numbers, I made a Python algorithm. It checked whether there are among the first $10$ million star numbers, $i$ succesive star succesive whose product is another star number. The only result that came up was $13\times37\times73=35113$.

Now using some heuristics. Let $S_n$ be the $n$th star number. The 'probability' that a number $x$ is a star number is proportional to $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$, so the 'probability' that $S_mS_{m+1}$ is a star number is on the order of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^4}}=n^{-2}$. Therefore, the 'expected' number of values of $m\geq n$ such that $S_nS_{n+1}$ is a star number is something like $\sum_{m=n}^{\infty}m^{-2}\approx n^{-1}$. So I would expect there to be only finitely many numbers $n$ such that $S_nS_{n+1}$ is a star number.
This reasoning works similarly for $S_nS_{n+1}S_{n+2}$ and $S_nS_{n+1}S_{n+2}S_{n+3}$. However, it is still heuristic so it doesn't prove anything. Maybe one can use analytic number theory? Or is there a more simple method?

A simple case to start with, would be products of 2 consecutive star numbers. For example, 13 and 37 are consecutive star numbers, but 13x37=481 is not a star number. In formulas this would boil down to the equation

$$(6n(n-1)+1)(6(n+1)n+1)=6m(m-1)+1$$

for integers $n,m$ with $n\geq2$. This is a quartic equation in two variables. It can be rewritten to

$$6n^4-4n^2=m^2-m.$$

This looks similar to a Pell equation. Is there a way to prove that this equation has no solutions at all? (Here we have $n>1$)

Comment: Prime star numbers are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A083577

Comment: $$n(n-1)=n^2-n=6ab\pm a\pm b$$ no?

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee that sounds interesting. Could you explain what a and b are?

Comment: Applied like the sieve of Sundaram $$(6a+1)(6b+1)=6(6ab+a+b)+1$$ or $$(6a-1)(6b-1)=6(6ab-a-b)+1$$ so basically useless

Comment: @Riemann, An equation $6n^4-4n^2=m^2-m$ can be reduced to $Y^2=24n^4-16n^2+1$.
Magma gives the only integer solutions $(n,Y)=(0,1),(\pm1,3)$.

Comment: @Tomita, I see that Magma is a powerful software. Did you prove using magma that these are the only solutions? Or did you only search for a large range of $n$ values?

Comment: @Riemann,I used the function IntegralQuarticPoints of Magma.
It says that all integral points are $(n,Y)=(0,1),(\pm1,3)$.